# Cisco VPN not working although it says connected

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to connect to my university network via VPN. I installed Cisco VPN and seems to be working normally. I connect to the network and it says connected, but when I check the IP address of my machine, I see that it is still using the local IP and  not the one from the university. If I check the syslog with the following command:

```
less /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager
```

I get in many places the message

```
NetworkManager[886]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/cscotun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

I suppose the problem is related to that. Is there an easy way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using openconnect that comes pre-installed or is available in the repositories. Works really well along with network-manager.

Comment: I tried that and i also get a "successful connection" but again if I check the ip address is not the correct one. Do I need to install a special driver to get that to work?

Comment: Since the IP is assigned by the other end(ASA or dhcp), are you sure that it's working all right?

Comment: How can i check that? I am not familiar with networks.

Comment: Perhaps I can rephrase -- Was it ever working for you? How do you know that you got a wrong IP? Do you have access to a Mac or Windows Box to verify your any/openconnect settings?

Comment: I rebooted my machine and installed ubuntu 14.04. Before it was working with Windows 7 and I never have problems with VPN connection. I am trying to connect to my university network via VPN in order to get some licenses that are only possible to download within the university domain. Despite VPN says it is connected successfully, I get an error saying that the domain is not an academic domain. I have tried many things but still I cant find a solution for the problem. I appreciate any help!